# Serialize heterogeneous map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have to serialize a map to file. First i put the map to the bytebuffer, then write the bytebuffer to file. In the load method, first read into bytebuffer the whole file, then fill the map from the bytebuffer. Currently i have this code (without the file handling):

Save method:

```
map<int, BaseClass*> myMap;
map<int, BaseClass*>::iterator it;
ByteBuffer bb;

bb.putUInt(myMap.size());
for (it = myMap.begin(); it!= myMap.end(); it++){
  bb.putUInt(it->first);
  it->second->save(bb); // the save method put the static type first, then the data
}
```

Load method

```
...// get the map size from bb
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
  int key = bb.getUInt() // in the real code there isn't signed/unsigned mismatch
  BaseClass* value = MyFactory.create(bb) // detailed later
  myMap.insert(key,value);
}
```

MyFactory.create:

```
BaseClass* MyFactory::create( ByteBuffer& bb){
  TypeEnum type = static_cast<TypeEnum>(bb.getUInt());
  BaseClass* value;

  switch (type){
    case DerivedClass1:
      value = new DerivedClass1()
      break;

    case DerivedClass2:
      value = new DerivedClass2()
      break;

    // etc...
  }

  value->load(bb);
  return value;
}
```

With this solution, i have a big enum TypeEnum, a long switch, and with every new derived class from base class i have to increase them. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can your map contains duplicate values? I mean for two different key the same BaseClass* object?

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459112/c-polymorphic-load-save/12460253#12460253.  Exactly the same technique is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is correct. However you migth want to consider following improvement:

Use smart pointer inside the factory::create. Because now it is not exception safe:

```
    std::auto_ptr<BaseClass> MyFactory::create(ByteBuffer& bb)
    {
        TypeEnum type = static_cast<TypeEnum>(bb.getUInt());
        std::auto_ptr < BaseClass > value;
        switch (type)
        {
            case DerivedClass1:
                value.reset(new DerivedClass1());
                break;
            case DerivedClass2:
                value.reset(new DerivedClass2());
                break;
        }
        value->load(bb);
        return value;
    }
```

This way if it fails on loading you will not have memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

In your place I'd consider using the [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library.